# Max-width of images in working in Explorer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I create a page in which I set max-width of imagesto 100%. But unfortunately IE is not supporting max-width of Images.

http://ezinetechnologies.com/dev/2015/design/idea/search.html

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You have max-width: 100%, but 100% of what? Of the parent width, right? But if the parent is an inline-block whose width is not set, so its width depends on the children, and in particular on the preferred width of the children.

The layout of this styling is undefined in the CSS specification. In particular, the intrinsic width of the kids in this case depends on the width of the parent which in turn depends on the intrinsic width of the kids. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float for the relevant spec text and note all the "does not define" bits.

Answer (score 0):

yes max-width on image not works on ie8 but works on  ie9+
refer this article http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/5/How-max-width-fails-in-IE8.html